# Does starting a profile in Mon Projet mean I applied to enter or remain in Canada?

Tags: visas, canada, quebec

I had a profile in [Mon Project](https://www.immigration-quebec.gouv.qc.ca/en/informations/news/news-2016/status-report-mpq.html) and now it is closed.

Today, I have applied for a visitor visa to Canada. They asked, "have you ever applied to enter or remain in Canada?"

I don't know if my Mon Project profile is an application to enter or remain.

Comment: @Traveller see [Lastest (sic) news - Mon projet Québec](https://www.immigration-quebec.gouv.qc.ca/en/informations/news/news-2016/status-report-mpq.html).  User100588: did you submit an application through that profile?

Answer (score 7):

Your profile in Mon Project is simply an [expression of interest](https://www.immigration-quebec.gouv.qc.ca/en/informations/application-permanent-selection-online.html). It is not itself an application to live in Canada. If you were not selected and did not receive an invitation letter (Certificat de sélection du Québec/Quebec Selection Certificate) to apply for permanent residence, and did not actually [make the application for permanent residence](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/quebec-skilled-workers.html), then you have not "applied to enter or remain in Canada" under this process.

Note that it's possible that you were already in Canada when you applied for the Mon Project. In this case, obviously you applied to enter or remain in Canada at some point prior to entering Canada.

Answer (score 3):

If you just created the profile and never used it to submit an application, you can answer *no.*  If you did submit an application, then the answer will of course be *yes.*  If you do not remember or are otherwise unsure, answer *yes* and supply as much detail as you can.